# Auditing Multiple Child Tables using Envers

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

Suppose I have Vechicle, Car, Person, Key Entities.

Vechicles has a list of Cars. 
Car have a List of Persons. 
Person has a ManytoOne relationship to Key.

So, Can I access the data in the Key table, if I call this method?

```
    VechicleVO vehicle = findAuditByRevision("1", 210);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can if Key have `@Audited` annotations and all needed collection fields (in Car, Person etc.) have annotation too.